# How to finding the same character in two string with python

Tags: python, string, compare

I need to finding the same character in two string.
One from open file, i get it using this and one from user input
 
Example :

```
x = raw_input('input x')
```

`y = open('file.txt' , 'r')
y = y.read()`

Assume we get the x = abcde and y = Compare
I need to find a situations where x == y
In the example first i need to find 'a' in y , and then 'b' , and etc,
I dont need to find all string that same, only sequentially from the first till last.
From my example we can guess that after 'a' there will be no 'b' in the y,
So its okay, i dont need to find the 'e' as in y have 'e'.

Comment: What do you mean by "find?" `x in y` would be sufficient if you just need to know that it's there. Separately: please don't write code this way -- your file object will never close.

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: @AdamSmith The main is im doing some text steganography, its for some mapping purpose. For that i need to know where is the location of each character in x that same like character in y. If it's not found i'll go to the next character and next character because for each character in x i need to get its information location for the next step.

Comment: @IanAuld the file contains a paragraphs of text which is string.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear on the question, but this might help you get on track.

```
x = raw_input('input x')
with open('file.txt', 'r') as thefile:
    for char in x:
        if char in thefile:
            print 'found character', char, 'in the file.'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but here is a piece of code that will find common characters in two strings and store them in a dictionary. The key in the dictionary is the common character found, and the value is a tuple containing the locations in each string where this character was found.

```
x = input('Enter value of x')
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
y = f.read()
f.close()
found = dict()

for i in enumerate(x):
    for j in enumerate(y):
        if i[1] == j[1]:
            # Store the result as:
            # found[character] = (location  in x, location in y)
            found[j[1]] = (i[0], j[0])

print found
```

For your example, the result would be {'a' : (0, 4), 'c' : (2, 0), 'e' : (4, 6)}